# Forcing locale and refreshing app for new language

Tags: android, localization, resources

I'm a forcing a locale after option changes:

```
public void forceLocale(Context ctx) {
    Locale.setDefault(getCurrentLocale());
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = getCurrentLocale();
    ctx.getResources().updateConfiguration(config, ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());   
}
```

I'd like the current activity to be displayed in a new Locale, but it doesen't happen. It's the same for the other activities.

I tried invalidate on onResume() of all my activities:

```
protected void onResume() {
    //if no custom locale, restore default
    if (StaticClass.locale.getCurrentLocale() == null)
        StaticClass.locale.restoreDefaultLocale();

    //force curretnt locale
    StaticClass.locale.forceLocale(this);

    //reload the view
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);
    vg.invalidate();

    super.onResume();
}
```

No effect. The app gets translated after it gets wiped out from memory and restarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the locale attribute set in your manifest `android:configChanges="locale"`? I also added this to my `onCreate()` in each activity

`if (Globals.langConfig != null)
            this.onConfigurationChanged(Globals.langConfig);`

then I override the `onConfigurationChanged()` in each activity

```
  @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
         newConfig = Globals.getUserLanguage(this);

super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
```

This may not be the best way but has worked for me for now. If you don't already, I think overriding the `onConfigurationChanged()` method may be your biggest problem